# How do I create a function .find_by_label(x), which is equivalent to .find_by(label: x)?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

My code has two functions which are essentially the same, except the parameters name. It would be great to merge two functions and make it generic. For example:

```
def self.find_global_variable_by_id(id) ## RSpec - Ok
    if result_global_unscoped = Variable.global.find_by(id: id)
        return result_global_unscoped
    end
    if result_global_scoped_workspace = Variable.find_by(id: id)
        return result_global_scoped_workspace
    end 
end
def self.find_global_variable_by_label(label) ## RSpec - Ok
    if result_global_unscoped = Variable.global.find_by(label: label)
        return result_global_unscoped
    end
    if result_global_scoped_workspace = Variable.find_by(label: label)
        return result_global_scoped_workspace
    end 
end
```

And I would like to have something like this:

```
def self.find_global_variable_by_<id/label>(x)
    if result_global_unscoped = Variable.global.find_by_<id/label>(x)
        return result_global_unscoped
    end
    if result_global_scoped_workspace = Variable.find_by_<id/label>(x)
        return result_global_scoped_workspace
    end 
end
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I wonder why you want to do that? I do not see any benefit in replacing `find_by(key...` with a more complex, harder to read and probably slower metaprogramming solution. If I saw such a metaprogramming solution I would refactor it into the no-metaprogramming version. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: You could replace your `find_global_variable_by_id` with `Variable.global.find_by(id: id) || Variable.find_by(id: id)`. And why not pass a `label: x` or `id: x` hash into your method instead of putting that information in the name? Or use keyword arguments to make the interface stricter.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, using method_missing.

```
def self.method_missing(message, *args, &block)
  if message =~ /find_global_variable_by_(id|label)/
    puts message
    # something
    return
  end
  super
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Klass
  def self.find_global_variable(h)
    Variable.global.find_by(h) || Variable.find_by(h)
  end
end
```

called

```
Klass.find_global_variable(id: id)
```

or

```
Klass.find_global_variable(label: label)
```

Comment: My people tell me that `ActiveRecord` has a `find_by` method, but as there is no "Rails" or "ActiveRecord" tag, and Ruby has no `find_by` method, I assume `find_by` here is a custom method that take a hash with a single key as an argument.

Comment: If it is Rails then `find_by(some_hash_of_attributes)` is the Right Thing anyway. This is pretty much what I'd do in either case.

Comment: My answer implements an earlier suggestion made by @muistooshort in a comment on the question, which I only noticed recently.